# Chrome App build - Offline mechanism support

Tags: angular

Need your suggestions, we had build a angular app which supports offline mechanism, now offline data is big enough for which we can’t relay on browser local storage. So to support on mobiles we used native android and IOS webkit UI and internally we are calling the entire angular application and on for offline we are downloading the file to device storage, somehow i agree this is not an ideal solution to it but at that we deleivered,
So i need help in two ways:
1) what is the best solution to approach offline aupport for big files
2) how to we package this angular application to chrome app and also support this big offline mechanism

Note: this is not a phonegap, cordova application

Comment: Your question is fairly broad, it's unclear what you mean by "best solution for storing files" and includes two only more or less related questions.  Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and try to make it a little more specific, also pointing out what you've researched already.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the reply, the major question is if i want to support offline mechanism (like books which is kind off 10MB each having around 10 books) which needs to be worked in all the platforms like ipad, iphone , android phones etc. so local storage is not the option as it will not support that much capacity of file size. So to support offline we used native route and stored in the device storage for IOS and Android, so now what is the approach to build for chrome apps?

Answer (score 0):

We also worked on Angular 1.x chrome application which supports offline storage including downloading PDF files to the device file system.

We have used the Cordova-sqlite-storage plugin https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage . It's a webSQL Database that supports both Andriod, IOS. The advantage of sqlite is we can store the information until the phone storage is full.

Inorder to download files. You can use cordova file plugin to download the files to device file system and store the location path in the SQlite DB.

Comment: Thanks suresh for downloading the file in chrome app cordova is the only approach for any native parroach is available? As i am new to chrome app development?

Comment: Yes, You need to wrap the Chrome App with Cordova to access native devices features like Database. Cordova act as a native bridge b/w your application and device API.